# How to link a custom stylesheet to a page template?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, stylesheet

If anyone could help me with this I'd be really grateful.
I know that this is a question that's been asked very frequently, however I've spent days looking at other people's posts trying to work out how to use my functions folder to link a custom stylesheet to a page template I'm working on.

So far, the code I've found that looks the most likely to work is this one -

```
if( is_page_template( 'work.php' ) ) {
wp_register_style("work-style", get_template_directory_uri() . 
"/css/page-template.css", '', '1.0.0');
wp_enqueue_style('page-template');
}
```

The page template I'm trying to create is called "work", as I've tried to add to the code, however something I'm doing isn't right, as it either uses the main stylesheet or it has no effect whatsoever, leaving me with a blank page between my header and footer.

You can see the code for my page template php below. (I'm very new to wordpress and coding in general, so if I've made any stupid errors, please let me know). I've developed the theme I'm using from scratch.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name:work
*/
?>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet"  
type="text/css"> 

<body>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="content" id= "workcontent">

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

<div class="entry">
<?php the_content(__('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;', 'kubrick')); ?>
</div>

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<div id="wrapper">      

<a href="/landscapes"><div class="albums" id= "album1"></div></a>
<a href="/seascapes"><div class="albums" id= "album2"></div></a>
<a href="/macro"><div class="albums" id= "album3"></div></a>
<a href="/cities"><div class="albums" id= "album4"></div></a>
<a href="/long-exposure"><div class="albums" id= "album5"></div></a>
<a href="/miscellaneous"><div class="albums" id= "album6"></div></a>

</div>
</div>

</body>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your work template is in the root of the theme folder and it is actually called work.php, as well as the fact that your css is in the css subfolder and is called template.css, you may want to modify your code as follows:

```
function enqueue_styles() { 
    if( is_page_template( 'work.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style('work-style', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/css/page-template.css', true, '1.0.0', 'all' );
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_styles');
```

obviously that goes into your functions.php file.  You can also place it directly in your work.php file, in which case you can skip the if and just place the following line at the top:

```
wp_enqueue_style('work-style', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/css/page-template.css', true, '1.0.0', 'all' );
```

Comment: Hi Dmitriy, I tried both and unfortunately neither of them worked. The functions folder is where I'd ideally like to put the code, however when I put your first suggestion in there, it came up with the message 

"Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'lwh_scripts' not found or invalid function name in /var/sites/l/lucieaverill.co.uk/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 496" 

Do you know what this means? 

The shorter code simply displayed itself at the top of the page.

Comment: My bad, copy and paste error, replace lwh_scripts with enqueue_styles

Comment: For the short code, wrap it with php tags:
<?php code goes here ?>

Comment: The error message has gone on the functions code, however it still isn't linking the page to the new stylesheet - I have a blank page between the header and footer. I think maybe there's a problem with the way I'm laying things out in my theme folder? I originally had the php pages and the css sheets in the folder together, but I just tried putting the css in a separate folder and this didn't have any effect. Here is a screenshot of the way I've organised the folder.  http://i.imgur.com/ckwK27a.jpg

Comment: What do you see when you do "view source"? do you see the new stylesheet there?  Wordpress expects a style.css to be in the root folder, at least with the header describing the theme.  You can define additional stylesheets in /css, but you do need a style.css in the root folder as well.  It does not need to be sourced by your template ,however.

Comment: I checked and it seems that the page template is reading both of them. The main style.css is at the top, and about a third of the way down the page, work-style.css is referenced. When I remove the code you gave me from the functions folder, the work-style.css disappears from the page source, so it looks like its working but something is getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

When enqueuing a style, you need to use the handle name you used to register it rather than the file name. In this case, you register the style as "work-style", so you should use that name to enqueue it, like this:

```
if( is_page_template( 'work.php' ) ) {
    wp_register_style('work-style', get_template_directory_uri() . 
    '/css/page-template.css', '', '1.0.0');
    wp_enqueue_style('work-style');
}
```